# Are the "calmed" B-Spec drivers useful?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I've noticed that in races without "micromanagement" the B-Spec drivers that are calmed have worse results that aggressive B-Spec drivers.

This is because when they are driving alone, they have very poor performance.

Aggressive B-Spec drivers make a lot of mistakes when they are at low levels, but when they level up they drive very well and they perform better.

Is it always better to have aggressive drivers, or should I maintain a calm driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calm one always drive with a lack of skill but then the aggressive drivers drive too aggressively. It's best to keep a driver between calm and aggressive.